# Remote validation in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, attributes

I have a Employee class: Id, Name, Occupation as parameters.
and have got Remote Validation on Name which contains a method- Given the name, checks if Employee name already exists in the database.Also displays the error message - Employee Name is in use if there exists any matching employee name in the database.

```
[Required, Display(Name="Employee name"),            
Remote("EmployeeNameValidation", "Employee", ErrorMessage = "Employee name is already in use!")]
public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
```

Now I do not want to display the error- if other fields in the form are changed except this  employee name but have to display the error, if it is same as other names in the database except this name.

Any input on this will be helpful

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: It is an employee form.  1. On editing, It should not throw me an error if i change Occupation. 2.  If I change the name, then it should check whether this employee name already exists in the database. I have done the second part.  But for the 1st part, it is throwing an error- "Employee name in use "